# Restricting user to scan QR code only once using ZXingScanner

Tags: qr-code, zxing

```
[My ScannerIntergrator][1]
```

i want a user to be able to scan the qrcode once,when he tries to scan it again he should get an error that he/she has already scanned the qrcode and he/she can scan it again maybe after a week

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.